# Flutter: Listview is not updating upon search

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, search

Everything is working fine, but ListView is not updating on onChanged. Although I am using setstate, but it is still not filtering the data. Note(The List is being filtered as I have printed it. The only problem is with the screen as it is not updating)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:travel_together_passenger/Models/user.dart';
import 'package:travel_together_passenger/Screens/User_Available_Carpools_TILE.dart';

class User_AvailableCarpools_LIST extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _User_AvailableCarpools_LISTState createState() =>
      _User_AvailableCarpools_LISTState();
}

class _User_AvailableCarpools_LISTState
    extends State<User_AvailableCarpools_LIST> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final checkcarpools = Provider.of<List<CarpoolDataShow>>(context) ?? [];
    final availablecarpools =
        checkcarpools.where((element) => element.seats > 0).toList() ?? [];
    List filteredcarpools =
        checkcarpools.where((element) => element.seats > 0 ).toList() ?? [];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search..'),
            onChanged: (text) {
              setState(() {
                filteredcarpools = availablecarpools
                    .where((element) => element.pickupaddress
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .contains(text.toLowerCase()))
                    .toList();
              });
            },
          )),
          Expanded(
            flex: 10,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: filteredcarpools.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return User_AvailableCarpools_TILE(filteredcarpools[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Provider.of<List<CarpoolDataShow>>(context) .method() ? method call is missing

Comment: do you mean that `build` method is not called after calling `setState()` inside `onChanged` callback?

Comment: Yes pskink, It is not getting called after setState()

Comment: i assume you added two `print`s: one inside `setState` and second inside `build` method and you see only the first? if so you found a serious bug in flutter i think

Comment: No, the issue is that by using SetState my screen is not updating with the filtered list. In simple words, listviewbuilder is not refreshing to the updated list with SetState

Comment: so `build()` method is called, right? and the list is not updating because you have `List filteredcarpools = ....` initialized inside that method

Comment: Where should I initialize it then?

Comment: read [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) - check all the points below `"State objects have the following lifecycle:"`

Comment: I am getting more confused after reading this.

Comment: If you could help me out with my piece of code, I will really appreciate you :)

Comment: what are you confused by? those points explain when the state object is created/destroyed and where you can add "one time initialization" for your `State` fields

Comment: What should i change in this code to make it working?

Comment: remove local variable `List filteredcarpools` - it should be a field in `_User_AvailableCarpools_LISTState` class

Comment: Field? like what? I am not getting what you are trying to tell me.

Comment: I did it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working now. A great thanks to pskink who gave me the hint.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:travel_together_passenger/Models/user.dart';
import 'package:travel_together_passenger/Screens/User_Available_Carpools_TILE.dart';

class User_AvailableCarpools_LIST extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _User_AvailableCarpools_LISTState createState() => _User_AvailableCarpools_LISTState();
}

class _User_AvailableCarpools_LISTState extends State<User_AvailableCarpools_LIST> {
  String txt = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final checkcarpools = Provider.of<List<CarpoolDataShow>>(context) ?? [];
    final availablecarpools =
        checkcarpools.where((element) => element.seats > 0).toList() ?? [];
    List filteredcarpools =
    availablecarpools.where((element) => element.pickupaddress.toLowerCase().contains(txt.toLowerCase())).toList() ?? [];
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'search..'
              ),
              onChanged: (text)
              {
                setState(() {
                  txt=text;
                });
                print(filteredcarpools);
              },

            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 10,
            child: ListView.builder(
              //shrinkWrap: true,
              key: UniqueKey(),
              itemCount: filteredcarpools.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
 //               print(filteredcarpools);
                return User_AvailableCarpools_TILE(filteredcarpools[index]);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```